# load a specific page on entering "www.mysite.com/myname" in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

My reqirement - when sitevisiter enters a url like "www.mysite.com/myname" and press enter then I need to load a lookup.aspx page.

how can i do that?

hoping for responce.

thanks in advance.

I have tried foll. code in web.config but it goes into Infinite loop.

Logic - on page_load of lookup.aspx
I am checking "myname" in DB and if that is present then I am redirecting page into "Home.aspx"
but if "myname" if not present in DB then redirects to nomemberfound.aspx page.

Comment: I have tried URL rewriting but it goes into infinite loop..           <rewrite url="~/([a-zA-Z]+)" to="~/lookup.aspx?user=$1" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got very simple solution for above -

You just need to add foll. code in web.config under ""

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteASPX">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true"/>                        
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="ScriptResource.axd" negate="true"/>                     
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern=".js" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="memberlogin.aspx?member={R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)  for routing/URL rewriting in asp.net

Here is an example without parameters:

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       routes.MapRoute(
       "My Route", //Route name
       "myname", //URL without parameters
       "~lookup.aspx" //The asp.net page
    );
    }
    void Application_Start()
    {
      RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);//Register route on startup
    }
```

If you are accepting parameters use this:

```
"myname/{param}" instead of `"myname"` in the above code.
```

and retrieve the value from codebehind as

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string param=Page.RouteData.Values["param"] as string;
}
```

Comment: we are using .net framwork 3.5 which is not supporting MapRoute(). suggest any alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("SomeRoute",
    "/{name}",
    "~/lookup.aspx");
}
```

To get name in lookup.aspx:

```
string name = Page.RouteData.Values["name"] as string;
    if (name != null)
    {
        if (name == "somename")
        {
           //Do something
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is nice [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) with examples on how to do it in .NET Framework 3.5. Hope it helps!

Comment: we are using .net framwork 3.5 which is not supporting MapPageRoute(). suggest any alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have IIS do it with [URL Rewrite 2.0](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

There's a video on that page which gives an overview. It's a pretty simple task.